# New webserver offering HTML for download, not for browsing

Tags: web-hosting

I recently purchased a hosting plan from a provider.
They gave me temporary url of accessing the hosting space, controlpanel, ftp details.

Now when I deleted all the files from public_html and put up a index.html, then on clicking on the temporary url,everytime a files gets downloaded (with download name).
What can be the issue?

Comment: This is the kind of question who should be dealt with service support from the hosting company. A possibility is that you have deleted .htaccess, but there are too many unknown variables...

Comment: I would put that as the answer @Osvaldo

Comment: I believe you should contact your provider about your issue. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the kind of question who should be dealt with service support from the hosting company. A possibility is that you have deleted .htaccess, but there are too many unknown variables...

Answer (score 1):

Your mime type is wrong on either host or the client. Probably the host. Change the *.htacess to include

```
AddType text/html *.html *.htm
```

Many subpar/budget hosts will have some kind of mime type control in their website control panels. Try to find it. It is usually associated with Apache.